# Reading Text Files with LINQ

Tags: linq

I have a file that I want to read into an array.

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"path to file");
```

I know that I can iterate through the array and find each line that contains a pattern and display the line number and the line itself.

My question is:

Is it possible to do the same thing with LINQ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well yes - using the `Select()` overload that takes an index we can do this by projecting to an anonymous type that contains the line itself as well as its line number:

```
var targetLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"foo.txt")
                      .Select((x, i) => new { Line = x, LineNumber = i })
                      .Where( x => x.Line.Contains("pattern"))
                      .ToList();

foreach (var line in targetLines)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", line.LineNumber, line.Line);
}
```

Since the console output is a side effect it should be separate from the LINQ query itself.

Comment: Bravo!!  I thought it would involve something that would allow me to use some sort of anonymous type, I just couldn't put the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ is possible.  However, since you want the line number as well, the code will likely be more readable by iterating yourself:

```
    const string pattern = "foo";
    for (int lineNumber = 1; lineNumber <= allLines.Length; lineNumber++)
    {
        if (allLines[lineNumber-1].Contains(pattern))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}. {1}", lineNumber, allLines[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

something like this should work

```
var result = from line in File.ReadAllLines(@"path")
             where line.Substring(0,1) == "a" // put your criteria here
             select line
```