# Read text file with dynamic conditional

Tags: c#, linq

I want to search content of text file using LINQ.

The search condition can be dynamically added.

[I've tried this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573851/reading-text-files-with-linq).

And modify source to dynamic add where condition:

```
var targetLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"foo.txt")
                      .Select((x, i) => new { Line = x, LineNumber = i });

if(true)
    targetLines.Where( x => x.Line.Contains("pattern"));

foreach (int condition in conditions)
    targetLines.Where(condition....);

var result = targetLines.ToList();

foreach (var line in result)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", line.LineNumber, line.Line);
```

But it's not working, where condition not applied in output.

Can I do it using LINQ?

Comment: `targetLines.Where` returns `IEnumerable<Type>` which you need to assign to some list, and that list will reflect filtered results which you wanted.

Comment: `int condition` looks terrible, I assume this is a pseudocode and you have list of predicates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've missed assignment:

```
if(true)
    targetLines = targetLines.Where( x => x.Line.Contains("pattern"));

foreach (var condition in conditions)
{
    targetLines = targetLines.Where(condition....);
}
```

`Where` method does not modify your target variable but produces new enumerable instead

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the following

```
var result = targetLines.Where( x => x.Line.Contains("pattern")).ToList(); 
///var result = targetLines.ToList();
```

---

You can see why in the documentation

[Enumerable.Where Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.
>
> Return Value
>
> An IEnumerable **that contains elements from the input sequence that
>   satisfy the condition**.

Comment: Search condition are not denfined, I want to use loop, if else....to add more condition. Search condition will be add dynamically.